# Erro ao chamar serviço REST - Url Encode

Tags: javascript, angular

Ao tentar fazer uma chamada HTTP GET, o serviço retorna um erro 500 pois na querystring deve ser utilizado o simbolo + encodado ao invés de espaços. Ex.: LOS+ANGELES = LOS%ANGELES

```
autocomplete(term: string){
    var url = this.serviceUrl + 'autocomplete?query=' + term + '&limit=5';
    console.log(url);
    return this.http
        .get(url, { headers: this.headers })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Erro retornado ao tentar fazer uma chamada passando algum texto com espaço, ex.: los angeles.

```
status
:
500
statusText
:
"Internal Server Error"
type
:
2
url
:
"https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/lists/utilities/geoservices/autocomplete?query=los%20a&limit=5"
_body
:
"{"status":"Unknown","reportingSystem":"RAF","timeStamp":"2017-09-21T12:03:40+00:00","type":"Application","errorCode":"ERR.RAF.APPLICATION","instance":"raf-darhlc006-9080","message":"Illegal character in query at index 75
```

Comment: Recomendo você utilizar o programa PostMan pra testar suas requisições. Se funcionar nele, você terá noção de como é feita uma requisição dessa forma. Olhando dessa forma eu não consegui encontrar nenhum erro, só testando mesmo pra saber. Boa sorte aí

Comment: eu só utilizo o postman para teste!

Comment: o que acontece é se eu passar uma valor na url com espaço, ex,: LOS ANGELES, a string é convertida em LOS%20ANGELES e o serviço retorna um erro 500, pois ele não aceita esse tipo de encode.

Comment: E tá funcionando essa forma que vc tá fazendo a requisição lá no PostMan?

Comment: Sim, olha só que louco, acho que entendi melhor, quando eu faço a requisição eu preciso passar no lugar dos espaços o simbolo + porem com ENCODE entende?

Comment: Sim, entendi. A Google coloca bastante esse símbolo de + nas pesquisas.

Comment: Que tipo de Content-Type você está usando na requisição?

Comment: @RenatoDiniz application/json